# What kind of medicine is Dr. Poison administering?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

**This contains major plot spoilers for *Wonder Woman* so proceed at your own risk.**

What is Dr. Poison giving General Ludendorff that helps him get stronger and she says will help restore his strength? I understand the whole idea was to make him look like Ares and she was helping him get his strength back, but when it is revealed he isn't Ares, this just raises more questions.

My initial thoughts were it was some kind of adrenaline which is how he was able to crush the revolver he held right after, but it doesn't explain why his face glowed. Did I miss something that revealed what this was?

I heard a theory that it might be a precursor to Venom (Used by Bane). I will keep this open to other theories and possibilities until an answer is presented from the director or cast.

Comment: I didn't watch the movie, so I wanna make sure. Was General Ludenorff doing exactly what Dr. Poison saying? Was he hypnotized or something?

Comment: He didn't seem like he was doing what she was saying, he was rough on her when she was unable to make her new chemical weapons fast enough.

Comment: Ares whispered some sort of special concoction into Dr. Poison's mind, it's probably some sort of alchemy which may have 'magical' properties.

Answer (score 5):

It wasn't any medicine that can be found in the actual world. Even adrenaline won't make you be able to crush a gun into pieces. Further, adrenaline is usually administered via syringe or pills, not by snorting it.

Based on all of this we can infer it was just a fictional creation of the film.

Comment: I understand this, but they did it multiple times and I understand the reason they did it to trick the audience, but it doesn't answer why she was giving him whatever drug it is, and why he needed to "regain his strength" he seemed perfectly healthy throughout the film. It seemed like it actually had a point to the plot or it might be used in later movies, other than just being a deceptive tool.

Comment: You may have missed a brief conversation between the General and one of his underlings as he entered the camp. The captain is complaining that his men haven't eaten or slept in three days. The General responds that neither has he, and shoots the underling for being a whiner. In real life, soldiers sometimes use amphetamines to overcome a lack of sleep and food. Dr. Poison has just provided Ludendorff with some sort of super-amphetamine to compensate for his lack of food and sleep.

Comment: That is a really good point - lack of sleep can kill you and it can certainly drain you cognitively and physically. Also, military history has a history of trying to create drugs to keep soldiers up and active, I believe methamphetamine was created or at least tested/used for this reason during WWII.